# Why do these ternary expressions give different results?

Tags: javascript, reduce

My first reduce returns an expression of the form:
`a + (condition)? b : c`, and my second reduce returns the equivalent (???) expression: `(condition)? a+b : a+c`  Why do they behave differently?

```js
function addressLengthWrong(address) {
  let keys = ['street', 'city', 'state', 'zip']
  return keys.reduce((acc, key) => acc + (address[key]) ? address[key].length : 0, 0)
}

let address = {
  street: 'My Street',
  city: '',
  state: '',
  zip: ''
}
console.log(`wrong address len ${addressLengthWrong(address)}`)

address.zip = '01234'
console.log(`wrong address len ${addressLengthWrong(address)}`)
```

Running the alternative...

```js
function addressLengthCorrect(address) {
  let keys = ['street', 'city', 'state', 'zip']
  return keys.reduce((acc, key) => (address[key]) ? acc + address[key].length : acc, 0)

}

address = {
  street: 'My Street',
  city: '',
  state: '',
  zip: ''
}
console.log(`correct address len ${addressLengthCorrect(address)}`)

address.zip = '01234'
console.log(`correct address len ${addressLengthCorrect(address)}`)
```

I have the excited sense that I'm about to learn something new.  What's going on here?

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence): `... + ...` precedence: 13, `... ? ... : ...` precedence: 4; the higher value "wins"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parentheses order is wrong.
Try this:

```
function addressLengthWrong(address) {
  let keys = ['street', 'city', 'state', 'zip']
  return keys.reduce((acc, key) => acc + (address[key] ? address[key].length : 0), 0)
}
```

You should wrap the entire ternary expression with parentheses, else the `acc` will be included.

Also, to quote Andreas' answer:

`... + ... precedence: 13, ... ? ... : ... precedence: 4; the higher value 'wins'`

Comment: Okay.  I see.  Thank you.  In other words, my wrong expression is just like `(a + (condition)) ? b : c` so Javascript lets me add an integer to a bool, and then interprets the sum as a bool which selects an integer?  Nutty!

Comment: Why should he wrap the whole thing in parenthesis? What is the order of precedence?

Comment: @Chipster See my comment

Comment: andreas summed it up well

Comment: @Andreas that makes sense. I think the answer could be improved if it included this information in it, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the ternary operation isn't correct in the first, and it isn't picking up on the initial value. Instead of addition (+), use += on the accumulator.

```
let a = 1, b = 2
let c = 0

c + a === 1 ? a : b //  fails, c = 0

c += a === 1 ? a : b //  success, c = 1
```